# RUBY: How to extract 5 digit number out of a String (only if existing)

Tags: ruby

I am looping over our projects and want to put them in an Array.
But since I want to match them based on Project numbers I have to extract the Project number first.
So I have projects like:

```
"dasdhdjdj (12367)"
"dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd (182)"
"daksdjsakjd"
"askdjksajd kjdkasjd"
```

So I just want to extract 5 digit numbers. Because project numbers with less digits are in the old format. Also I want to exclude all projects where no project number was included in the name.

I read about the regex function but I don't really found out if I can use it for my case?
I think it would be best if it just extracts the number when it fits the 5-digit conversion and extracts nothing (empty string) if it doesn't.

Would be glad if someone could help.

Best regards

Comment: Regex is definitely the (simple) answer. `project_name.match(/\d{5}/)` will do the job...

Comment: _"I am looping over our projects"_ – show that code, please. A regex would probably work, but depending on how you retrieve the initial projects list, there might be better options. (e.g. database → query, filesystem → glob)

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov, note `"abc (123456789)".match(/\d{5}/) # => #<MatchData "12345">`.

Comment: @RobertYarborough : If one line in the procect file had the entry `blabla(12345) xxxx22798 yyy (444)`, would you like to get something extracted from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Strign#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#method-i-scan) might work for you:

```
"dasdhdjdj (12367)".scan(/\b\d{5}\b/)
#=> ["12367"]
"dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd (182)".scan(/\b\d{5}\b/)
#=> []
"daksdjsakjd".scan(/\b\d{5}\b/)
#=> []
"askdjksajd kjdkasjd".scan(/\b\d{5}\b/)
#=> []
```

Comment: thanks, that worked perfectly :)

just one little thing. i put all of the numbers into my new projects array which looks like that now:

[["10367"], ["20166"], ["10408"], ["10395"], ["10409"], ["10373"], ["10308"], ["10390"], ...]

what is the easiest way to get rid of the brackets? because that looks like i have plenty of arrays inside of an array right?

Comment: When you are sure that there is only one number per string then just call `.scan(/\d{5}/).first` to return the first (and only) number that was found in the string.

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is at most one project id number per string.

If, as in the example, the project id must be enclosed in parentheses, you may extract a valid project id, if present, as follows:

```
r = /(?<=\()\d{5}(?=\))/
str[r]
```

For example,

```
"dasdhdjdj (12367)"[r]
  #=> "12367" 
"dasdhdjdj 12367"[r]
  #=> nil 
"dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd (182)"[r]
  #=> nil 
"dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd (123678)"[r]
  #=> nil 
"daksdjsakjd"[r]
  #=> nil
```

As seen, only the first of these example strings contains a valid project id.

The regular expression reads, "match five digits that are preceded by a left parenthesis and followed by a right parentheses". `(?<=\()` is a *positive lookbehind* and `(?=\))` is a *positive lookahead*.

See [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D). This doc shows that we could alternatively write

```
r = /\((\d{5})\)/
"dasdhdjdj (12367)"[r,1]
  #=> "12367"
```

This regular expression reads, "match a left parenthesis that is followed by five digits that are saved to capture group 1 (`(\d{5})`), followed by a right parentheses".

---

If the project id need not be enclosed in parentheses, but cannot be preceded nor followed by a word character, you may write

```
r = /\b\d{5}\b/
str[r]
```

For example,

```
"dasdhdjdj (12367)"[r]
  #=> "12367" 
"dasdhdjdj 12367"[r]
  #=> "12367" 
"dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd 12367A"[r]
  #=> nil 
"dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd (182)"[r]
  #=> nil 
"dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd 123678"[r]
  #=> nil 
"daksdjsakjd"[r]
  #=> nil
```

The regular expression reads, "match five digits preceded and followed by a word boundary (`\b`)".

Note that without the word boundaries

```
"dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd 123678"[/\d{5}/] 
   #=> "12367"
```

---

If the project id need not be enclosed in parentheses and could be preceded or followed by any character other than a digit, you may write the following.

```
r = /(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)/
str[r]
```

For example,

```
"dasdhdjdj (12367)"[r]
  #=> "12367" 
"dasdhdjdj 12367"[r]
  #=> "12367" 
"dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd 12367A"[r]
  #=> "12367"  
"dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd (182)"[r]
  #=> nil 
"dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd 123678"[r]
  #=> nil
```

This regular expression reads, "match five digits that are neither preceded nor followed by a digit". `(?<!\d)` is a *negative lookbehind*; `(?!\d)` is a *negative lookahead*.

---

The results could be save to an array as follows. Suppose

```
arr = ["dasdhdjdj (12367)",
       "dasdhdjdj 12368",
       "dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd 12369A",
       "dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd (182)",
       "dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd 123678"]
```

and (for the last case considered)

```
r = /(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)/
```

We may then write

```
arr.each_with_object([]) do |s,a|
  id = s[r]
  a << id unless id.nil?
end
  #=> ["12367", "12368", "12369"]
```

or

```
arr.map { |s| s[r] }.compact
   #=> ["12367", "12368", "12369"]
```

(though I confess a personal distaste for `compact`). One might alternatively save the results to a hash.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |s,h|
  id = s[r]
  h[s] = id unless id.nil?
end
  #=> {"dasdhdjdj (12367)"=>"12367",
  #    "dasdhdjdj 12368"=>"12368",
  #    "dasidsadjdasjd dkasjd 12369A"=>"12369"}
```